# Recreate Solidify Thickness Clamp in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, geometry

I am trying to build the Solidify modifier in geometry nodes. Generally this is simple as there are many ways to offset a copy of the geometry. And we have Extrude to create the Rim. However, I am stuck on the Thickness Clamp option, which is the primary thing I need.

The docs give [this description](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html), but its not specific enough to build from:

[image]

I've also looked into the source code. The relevant functions seem to be in [*source\blender\modifiers\intern\MOD_solidify_extrude.cc*](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/source/blender/modifiers/intern/MOD_solidify_extrude.cc). This snippet seems to be it, and starts at line 869 (but there are other snippets that start with if (do_clamp) so I'm not entirely sure.) I'm not an advanced enough coder to figure out exactly what's going on here.

```
    if (do_clamp) {
  const float clamp_fac = 1 + (do_angle_clamp ? fabsf(smd->offset_fac) : 0);
  const float offset = fabsf(smd->offset) * smd->offset_clamp * clamp_fac;
  if (offset > FLT_EPSILON) {
    float *vert_lens_sq = static_cast<float *>(
        MEM_malloc_arrayN(verts_num, sizeof(float), "vert_lens_sq"));
    const float offset_sq = offset * offset;
    copy_vn_fl(vert_lens_sq, int(verts_num), FLT_MAX);
    for (i = 0; i < edges_num; i++) {
      const float ed_len = len_squared_v3v3(vert_positions[edges[i][0]],
                                            vert_positions[edges[i][1]]);
      vert_lens_sq[edges[i][0]] = min_ff(vert_lens_sq[edges[i][0]], ed_len);
      vert_lens_sq[edges[i][1]] = min_ff(vert_lens_sq[edges[i][1]], ed_len);
    }
    if (do_angle_clamp) {
      for (i = 0; i < verts_num; i++) {
        float cos_ang = cosf(vert_angs[i] * 0.5f);
        if (cos_ang > 0) {
          float max_off = sqrtf(vert_lens_sq[i]) * 0.5f / cos_ang;
          if (max_off < offset * 0.5f) {
            vert_angles[i] *= max_off / offset * 2;
          }
        }
      }
      MEM_freeN(vert_angs);
    }
    else {
      for (i = 0; i < verts_num; i++) {
        if (vert_lens_sq[i] < offset_sq) {
          float scalar = sqrtf(vert_lens_sq[i]) / offset;
          vert_angles[i] *= scalar;
        }
      }
    }
    MEM_freeN(vert_lens_sq);
  }
}
```

Has anybody built this already, or can explain what's happening?